# Deploy Azure Cloud Service using Azure Automation Powershell DSC

Tags: azure, automation, dsc

We are using Azure Automation DSC and were able to do simple things like create Automation account, create Resource group, VM creation and even able to deploy a web site on the target VM. All using powershell scripting.
How can we deploy Azure Cloud Services (web role / worker role)? what are the cmdlets? Any pointers? Please help. 
What more things can be achieved using this? Moreover what limitations we can expect here.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Azure DSC is really focused on Azure's Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) offering.  Basically you can configure virtual servers (Windows and Linux) hosted on Azure.

To manage configurations for other services in Azure it is recommended to utilize [Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/) (ARM) which will allow you to define and configure Azure services in JSON.

Microsoft offers a lot of Quick Start ARM templates that can be accessed at the [Azure Quickstart](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/) site.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the reply. What i am looking here is any help regarding creating Azure Cloud Service using ARM. We were able to deploy web sites on VMs through ARM DSC. And looking forward to deploy azure cloud service (web role / worker roles etc.).